# How can I check if a new browser tab was opened?

Tags: playwright

In a web application (implemented in React), when I press a specific button, then a new browser tab is opened. I would like to check that this happened and if the URL of the new tab is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement it like that

```
// @ts-check
const playwright = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.org/');

  // Important to "start" this promise before the window.open() could happen
  const newPagePromise = new Promise(resolve => context.once("page", resolve))

  // Imagine some internal window.open() logic
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.open("https://github.com/microsoft/playwright", "_blank")
    }, 3 * 1000)
  })

  // Here we are waiting until the page has been opened
  const newPage = await newPagePromise

  // Since its a normal Page instance, we can now assert the URL of it
  console.log(newPage.url(), await newPage.title())

  await browser.close();
})();
```

See it here interactively on Try Playwright: https://try.playwright.tech/?s=g8vb1si

Comment: What about a new page that the test has no control over?  Such as an email that was sent to a new tab (in a dev environment) from the backend?

Comment: Can you test the newPage with locators the same way as the original page (i.e. newPage.locator('h1:has-text("microsoft")')?  Or do you only have access to the url() and title().

Answer (score 0):

```
test('new tab', async ({ page, context }) => {
  // init test....

  const [newTab] = await Promise.all([
        context.waitForEvent('page'),
        page.click('a[target="_blank"]') // your new tab logic here...
  ]);

  await expect(newTab.url()).toBe('http://test');
});
```